# Commutators polynoms Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

Define the commutator $[a, b] := ab − ba$.
I have to show:
if $[a, b]=0$ follows $[f(a),g( b)]=0$ where $f,g$ are polynomials in the ring $K[X]$.
my idea:
$f(a)=a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n$,
$g(b)=b_1+b_2+\cdots+b_n$,
then $[f(a),g(b)]=a_ib_i-b_ia_i=0$.

Answer (score 0):

You don't know what $f$ and $g$ are, and you can't just pick one that you want. It suffices though to show that for all $i,j\geq 0$ we have $[a^i,b^j] = 0$ because the bracket is linear. We have that
$$ab-ba = 0$$
so
$$ab = ba$$
Hence, by induction you can show that
$$a^ib = ba^i$$
since
$$a^ib = a^{i-1}ba$$
and hence by a second induction we get
$$a^ib^j = b^ja^i$$
hence
$$[a^i,b^j] = 0$$